# Accept pairing request programmatically - Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

A remote device is sending my application a pairing request and it requires a pin to be entered for pairing (A dialog appears and asks for pin). I have the pin and I want to write a program that could provide the pin to the pairing request.

Can someone please tell me how to accept the pairing request in a program and somehow not show the dialog asking user to enter the pin.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 2.3.3 there are the methods:

`createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()`

and:

`listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord()`

in the BluetoothAdapter.